# How do you make a Roman numeral numbered list in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, text-formatting, browser-addons

I know how to make a bullet list (<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>) 
and a numbered list (<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>) in Gmail.

Is it possible to make a numbered list that uses Roman numerals? (preferably by keyboard shortcut)

Answer (score 3):

There isn't such option nor keyboard shortcut in Gmail, but you could do it manually if you install this extension for Gmail: **[https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/free-html-editor-for-gmai/ioinaaeeacahcmbgfmeaaofhfkijpdeb)**

- create a usual numbered list
- click on the extension icon next to **Send**
- in **`<ol>`** tag add **`type="I"`** so it will look like: **`<ol type="I">`**
- click on **<kbd>`Save and Close`</kbd>** button on the top
- done!

[image: 00]

---

...here are some other options:

[image: 0]